# Should I store polygons for use in Google Maps locally or in Fusion Tables?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygon, google-fusion-tables

I'm working on a game/visualization that will involve 90 or so municipalities on a map. I want to toggle the color of individual municipality polygons as a user completes certain tasks.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I could store all the municipal borders in a fusion table. Then I could make two layers: one that stores municipalities of one color, and then another layer with the other color. The downfall of this is I would end up querying FT over and over to grab an updated layer each time I needed to change a municipality.

The other way I can think of to handle this would be to store all the coordinates in my own array, and loop through it to generate the initial polygons with google.maps.Polygon. Then any time I needed to change a polygon's color, I could just call that particular polygon.

But all these coordinates will make the js file balloon to over 500kb.

Is either of these the best option, or have I overlooked a different solution?

Comment: If you have the polygons in a FusionTable you can [style them dynamically](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#fusion_table_styles) (on one table)

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. Thanks for pointing that out.